# Exchange the values between two columns based on a condition using R

Tags: r

I have got the following df. I want if the value in the dm column is less than 20000, then that value should go to the nd column. Similarly, if the value in the nd column is greater then 20000 then that value should go to the dm column

```
structure(list(id = c(1, 2, 3), nd = c(NA, 20076, NA), dm = c(10113, 
NA, 10188)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))
```

I want my final df to look like this

```
structure(list(id = c(1, 2, 3), nd = c(10113, NA, 10188), dm = c(NA, 
20076, NA)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))
```

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ifelse` is your friend for this.

## base R

```r
transform(df,
  nd = ifelse(dm < 20000, dm, nd), 
  dm = ifelse(nd > 20000, nd, dm)
)
#   id    nd    dm
# 1  1 10113    NA
# 2  2    NA 20076
# 3  3 10188    NA
```

Note that this works in base R because unlike `dplyr::mutate`, the calculation for the `dm=` (second) expression (and beyond) *does not* see the change from the previous expressions, so the `nd` that it sees is the original, unchanged `nd`.

We can *also* use the temporary-variable trick illustrated in the `dplyr` example below:

```r
df |>
  transform(
    nd2 = ifelse(dm < 20000, dm, nd),
    dm2 = ifelse(nd > 20000, nd, dm)
  ) |>
  subset(select = -c(nd, dm))
```

and then rename `nd2` to `nd` (etc).

## dplyr

Because `mutate` "sees" the changes immediately, we need to store into other variables and then reassign.

```r
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  mutate(
    nd2 = ifelse(dm < 20000, dm, nd),
    dm2 = ifelse(nd > 20000, nd, dm)
  ) %>%
  select(-nd, -dm) %>%
  rename(nd=nd2, dm=dm2)
#   id    nd    dm
# 1  1 10113    NA
# 2  2    NA 20076
# 3  3 10188    NA
```

Comment: Nice. This is cleaner, more readable syntax than my effort.

Answer (score 1):

Another base R option using `apply`:

```r
as.data.frame(t(apply(df, 1, function(x) {
  if(x[2] > 20000 | x[3] < 20000) x[c(1, 3, 2)] else x})))
#>   id    dm    nd
#> 1  1 10113    NA
#> 2  2    NA 20076
#> 3  3 10188    NA
```

<sup>Created on 2023-02-18 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>